# Explicitly expire tokens acquired from AWS Security Token Service

Tags: aws-java-sdk, aws-sts

Can I explicitly expire session tokens acquired from AWS STS service using AWS Java SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to expire tokens issued by STS.

However, if the STS token was based based a role, you can **change the permissions associated with the role**, which will then impact users who are using the STS credentials.

The `AWSRevokeOlderSessions` does this by checking the login time, denying permissions if the session is older than a particular time. This affects the role, but does not in itself expire the STS credentials.